# How do i update three.js scene only once on dat.gui preset change?

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

DAT.GUI fires the change event for each property when i change the preset. In this case the scene updates two times:

```
addGui( 'Ambientcolor', ambient.color.getHex(), function( val ) {
    ambient.color.setHex( val );
    renderer.render( scene, camera ); // renderScene()
}, true );
addGui( 'Ambient intensity', ambient.intensity, function( val ) {
    ambient.intensity = val;
    renderer.render( scene, camera ); // renderScene()
}, false, 0, 2.0 );

function addGui( name, value, callback, isColor, min, max ) {
    var node;
    param[ name ] = value;
    if ( isColor ) {
                    node = gui.addColor( param, name ).onChange( function() {
                    callback( param[ name ] );
                } );
    } else if ( typeof value == 'object' ) {
                    node = gui.add( param, name, value ).onChange( function() {
                    callback( param[ name ] );
                } );
    } else {
                    node = gui.add( param, name, min, max ).onChange( function() {
                    callback( param[ name ] );
                } );
            }
    gui.remember(param);
    return node;
}
```

I got 27 controllers = 27 renderings for each preset change. What is the propper way to make this scene-update?

**EDIT 1**
Maybe it have something to do with the callback function? 
I made a (not so pretty) workaround for now. The controller update takes about 5 msec on a crappy graphiccard. So i made a render function with a timer to prevent the rendering to be fired more than one time each 20 msec.

```
    var t0=0, t1=0;
    var perf=[]; // for displaying time
    function renderScene() {
         t1 = performance.now();
         perf.push(t1);
         if (Math.abs(t1-t0)>20) {
             t0 = performance.now();
             var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 19);

             function myTimer() {
                 renderer.render( scene, camera );
                    perf.push(performance.now());
                    clearInterval(myVar);
                    alert(perf.join('\n'));
             }
         }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**
I have eliminated the callback function but i still got a render-update problem. In this example where i create 2 folders with 2 controllers i get 4 sceneupdates on 1 presetchange.

```
var o1 = gui_mesh.addFolder('Mesh1');
AddObjectToFolder(o1,0,mesh1);
var o2 = gui_mesh.addFolder('Mesh2');
AddObjectToFolder(o2,1,mesh2);

function AddObjectToFolder(f,fi,mesh) {
      paramMesh[fi][ 'XY Scale' ] = mesh.scale.x;
      f.add( paramMesh[fi], 'XY Scale', 0.50 , 6.00 ).onChange( function(val) {
                    mesh.scale.x = val;
                    mesh.scale.y = val;
                    renderer.render( scene, camera );
      } );


      paramMesh[fi][ 'Repeat x' ] = mesh.material.map.repeat.x;
      f.add( paramMesh[fi], 'Repeat x', 0, 2.0 ).onChange( function(val) {
                    mesh.material.map.repeat.x = val;
                    mesh.material.map.repeat.y = val;
                    mesh.material.map.needUpdate=true;
                    renderer.render( scene, camera );
       } );
       gui_mesh.remember(paramMesh[fi]);

 }
```

It's obviously why with the render-function in every onChange event, but how do i do this right?

**EDIT 3 / Alternative solution**

I came up with another approach to this problem by using Watch.JS together with DAT GUI. Here's the function that have to be coded for every component you need. In this case a three.js project:

```
var guiObj = guiObj || {}


function guiWatch(idName) {

    this.params = {};
    this.paramObj={};

    this.setVal= function(name,val){
        this.paramObj[name].setValue(val);
        this.paramObj[name].updateDisplay();
    }

    this.createFloat = function(name, title, min, max, val0, steps, func) {
        this.params[name]=val0;
        this.paramObj[name]=this.gui.add(this.params, name, min, max).step(steps);
        watch(this.params, name, func);
    }

    this.createColor = function(name, title, val0, func) {
        this.params[name]=val0;
        this.paramObj[name]=this.gui.addColor(this.params, name);
        watch(this.params, name, func);
    }

}
```

Then i initialize some Gui's (not folders):

```
guiObj['editRepair']= new guiWatch('guiEditRepair',function(val){ renderScene(); });
guiObj['editPaint']= new guiWatch('guiEditPaint',function(val){ renderScene(); });
```

And then the creation of components:

```
guiObj['editRepair'].createColor('color','Color','#ffffff',
      function(prop, action, val){ 
           var hCol=hexToRgb(val);
          setColorDifMap(hCol.r,hCol.g,hCol.b); 
});

guiObj['editRepair'].createFloat('size','Size',2,200,50, 1,
      function(prop, action, val){ 
          scaleCursor(val,false); 

}); 

guiObj['editPaint'].createColor('color','Color','#ffffff',
    function(prop, action, val){ 
          var hCol=hexToRgb(val);
          setColorDifMap(hCol.r,hCol.g,hCol.b);
});

guiObj['editPaint'].createFloat('size','Size',2,200,50, 1,
      function(prop, action, val){ 
          scaleCursor(val,false); 
});

guiObj['editPaint'].createFloat('depth','Depth',2,256,10, 1,
      function(prop, action, val){ 
          setTextureDepth(val); 
});
```

I found this to be a simple way to create components. But of course there's always something smarter out there ;-)

Comment: AFAIK, addGui is not a dat.gui function. Hard to help without seeing that function. dat.gui change events are documented [here](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#7--Events)

Comment: Ahh sorry... i have updated the code.

Comment: not sure, but maybe something to to with the `node` variable. Your addGui function returns it, but you don't store it. Where is the `param` variable you use in addGui come from? is it defined outside of the addGui function? Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes param is defined outside the addGui function, initializing the color: param = { color: '0xffffff' }; - it is all stored in the wp database. I have left out a lot to make it simple. Everything works but the renderer that get's fired on all gui-controller updates when i change a preset.

Comment: You put what is returned from `gui.add` into the `node` variable, but this `node` variable is local to the function and gets overridden every time you call your `addGui` function. If I were you, I would get rid of your `addGui` function, it makes thing more confusing, and does not seem to make things any more efficient, because you still have to call it for every item you want to add.

Comment: I have updated the code, but i guess that the problem is where i update the renderer. Is there maybe something like a "gui.onAfterChange" event where i can put the renderer.render() ?

Comment: @Flemming Have you manage to find a workaround for this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @MihaiTodor i have updated my post ... maybe you can use it?

Comment: @Flemming Thanks for the update! That's an interesting approach. I wasn't aware of Watch.JS, but I might be able to use it too. It's a shame that dat.gui doesn't expose this functionality.